# Enabling SSL/HTTPS on my Wordpress site running on AWS Cloud

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have issues with enabling SSL/HTTPS certificate for my web site.

Context:

- I have installed Bitnami Wordpress on AWS.
- Webserver (EC2 instance) is running in Frankfurt region
- When I purchased a domain name from AWS, I ended up automatically in "Global" region in which Hosted Zone was automatically created.
- I have created elastic IP and added A entry into DNS with elastic IP
- the entries (after several attempts to make this work) in DND (route 53) are: 2 A records where one points to my-domain-name.com and other to [www.my-domain-name.com](http://www.my-domain-name.com), 1 MX, 1 NS, 1 SOA, 4 CNAME, 3 TXT entries

Tried with following approaches

- With Certificate Manager (Frankfurt zone) I have requested a certificate and created distribution list -> did not work
- Tried also to connect with my Windows PC using ssh and pem file (following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q2AdWoPNios) -> connection did not work after installing Cygwin and making permission changes. Error messages "Permissions for key-pair.pem are too open..." or "Permission denied (public key".

Now, all this aside... is it really so damn hard to add a simple SSL/HTTPS to a website?
Does a person doing this need to have 3 PhDs from MIT? If I registered everything over AWS why can't I simply enable this option? Instead I am jumping from one tutorial to another and from wanting to add this SIMPLE functionality I ended up going through tutorials about changing Windows permissions on a file, installing and using Cygwin, learning how to work with it, researching how to change the inheritance of a file etc etc etc.

I just want to add SSL / HTTPS to my site and work on a site, not learn everything there is to learn about Cloud, Windows and Cygwin...

Can anyone please offer a simple, step-by-step solution? Tx!

Comment: Digital Ocean has good tutorials. "Droplet" === "EC2 Instance" https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it will be better handled on https://serverfault.com/.